# Does switching to a non-company Gmail account in the same browser mean you won't be tracked?

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business

Let's say you're on your own personal computer that has been scanned by a third party security professional and doesn't have any kind of spyware. If you log in to Google Chrome with your personal Gmail as well as a company account that uses Google Workspace (or whatever the plans are called that Google sells to companies) AND your company google account says "Your browser is managed by ", does this mean when you switch in Chrome to your personal Gmail account via the dropdown in the upper right corner of the browser that since you are using your personal Gmail account your company cannot view browser history that relates to browser activity via your personal Gmail account? (i.e., is Google kind enough not to send that data to your company?)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how history gets associated between Google accounts and what a company managed profile has access to...

Comment: your chatting with a Bot

Comment: Thank you, I was adding context to avoid any more unhelpful comments by the bot :)